# Sumar contenido de una columna

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Necesito sumar el contenido de una tabla que estoy cargando con `ng_repeat`. Podría ser también recorriendo todo el objeto desde el controller.js pero tampoco ubico bien cómo.

```
dato1 dato2 dato3
xx    xx    5
xx    xx    8
--    --    13 tfoot
```

Comment: Hola CristianBonk, por favor crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema mejor. Las preguntas sin un enunciado claro, no son de ayuda a otros usuarios. Lee [ask] en el centro de ayuda para más información. Y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Answer (score 0):

ng-repeat= "item in Data "

col-1       col-2               col-3
item.dato1  item.dato2   (item.dato1 +  item.dato2)

Comment: Hola elshazer, esta respuesta ha sido marcada como de muy baja calidad por la comunidad. por favor lee [answer] y edita tu publicación siguiendo los consejos que encontrarás allí. Tal y como está redactada ahora no se entiende qué es lo que estás sugiriendo o cómo solucionaría el problema.